# Why am I unable to run a docker container in my cloud devshell?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am following the tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/quickstart-docker . I've built the image & it is pushed to Google's gcr.io registry.

```
$ gcloud auth configure-docker
gcloud credential helpers already registered correctly.

$ docker run --init gcr.io/foo-bar-111111/quickstart-image
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/foo-bar-111111/quickstart-image:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication.
See 'docker run --help'.

$ docker-credential-gcr configure-docker
/home/wonderwoman/.docker/config.json configured to use this credential helper for GCR registries

$ docker run --init gcr.io/foo-bar-111111/quickstart-image
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/foo-bar-111111/quickstart-image:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication.
See 'docker run --help'.

$ docker pull gcr.io/foo-bar-111111/quickstart-image:latest
Please login prior to pull:
error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `docker-credential-gcr/helper: could not retrieve GCR's access token: credentials not found in native keychain`
```

What have I missed ?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `gcloud` as a [Docker credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#gcloud_as_a_docker_credential_helper):

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

So you must use [gcloud docker](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/docker) to `docker pull` your image from the docker registry. `gcloud docker` still uses Docker underneath, but injects the Docker client with Container Registry credentials before handing off to Docker.

Using your example:

```
gcloud docker pull gcr.io/foo-bar-111111/quickstart-image:latest
```

You will likely have to use `sudo` too, making the full command:

```
sudo gcloud docker pull gcr.io/foo-bar-111111/quickstart-image:latest
```

Comment: The docs has a little warning that reads *gcloud docker is only recommended for Docker client versions older than 1.13*. This was the thing that confused me. I will try your suggestions.